# Time based Enable/Disable WooCommerce add to cart functionality

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm searching for a method to make this:

- From Monday - Sunday from 5pm to 2pm the add to cart is enabled, before or after this time, the add to cart button needs to be disabled.
- On Tuesday the complete day, the Shop is closed, so the add to cart is disabled.

I found this snippet to disable the add to cart but without the time and day specification:

```
/**
 * @snippet       WooCommerce Holiday/Pause Mode
 * @how-to        Watch tutorial @ https://businessbloomer.com/?p=19055
 * @sourcecode    https://businessbloomer.com/?p=20862
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @testedwith    WooCommerce 2.6.4
 */

// Trigger Holiday Mode
add_action ('init', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_holiday_mode');

// Disable Cart, Checkout, Add Cart
function bbloomer_woocommerce_holiday_mode() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'bbloomer_wc_shop_disabled', 5 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_wc_shop_disabled', 5 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'bbloomer_wc_shop_disabled', 5 );
}

// Show Holiday Notice
function bbloomer_wc_shop_disabled() {
    wc_print_notice( 'Our Online Shop is Closed Today :)', 'error');
}
```

My English is not good, but I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to get you started, this piece of code will check if today is Tuesday and if it is then the add to cart functionality will be disabled.

```
function bbloomer_woocommerce_holiday_mode() {

    $disable_cart = my_wc_disable_add_to_cart();

    if( $disable_cart ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment', 20 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'bbloomer_wc_shop_disabled', 5 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_wc_shop_disabled', 5 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'bbloomer_wc_shop_disabled', 5 );
    }
}

function my_wc_disable_add_to_cart() {
    // Tuesday is day number 2 of the week
    $day_of_week = date("w", current_time());

    if( $day_of_week === 2 )
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

It will be a similar process adding the other time criteria for enabling/disabling the cart.

Answer (score 0):

i'm trying to write my own snippet and this is what I achieved so far:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'disable_checkout_sunday' );
function disable_checkout_sunday(){
if (date(D) == "Sun"){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
remove__action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form');
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form');
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review');
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_checkout_payment');

 }
}
```