# Time for category add to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I used this code [Time based Enable/Disable Add to Cart in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369492/time-based-enable-disable-add-to-cart-in-woocommerce)
to close my store based on time setting.

How can make this code work for certain category only and not show message in all pages?

Comment: What have you tried so far? now you have exactly the same code as the url you shared

Comment: sorry my mistake, I'm not a programmer