# Only allow purchases on a time range for selected week days in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce, product

For a non profit, I need to create a function that first checks the time and if the time is within range, check what day it is. They only allow purchases on `Tuesdays`, `Thursdays` and `Saturdays` within the given time.

I've tried many things and *[Time based Enable/Disable Add to Cart in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369492/time-based-enable-disable-add-to-cart-in-woocommerce/54373061#54373061)* answer has inspired my code below:

```
function opening_hours() {
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

    $opening_time = mktime('10', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
    
    $closing_time = mktime('17', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));

    $now = time();

    return ($now >= $opening_time && $now <= $closing_time) ? true : false;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'disable_purchases_on_closed_days', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'disable_purchases_on_closed_days', 10, 2 );
function disable_purchases_on_closed_days( $purchasable, $product ) {

    // check if the time is correct for opening hours
    if ( opening_hours() ) {

        // if the time is right, make sure it is one of the correct days (tuesday, thursday or saturday)
        if (date('N') != 2 || date('N') != 4 || date('N') != 6){

            // if not the correct day, disable purchase
            $purchasable = false;

            return $purchasable;
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'cart_and_checkout_opening_hours' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'cart_and_checkout_opening_hours' );
function cart_and_checkout_opening_hours() {

    if ( ! opening_hours() ) {

        wc_add_notice( __("The online store is currently closed. You can view products, but purchases are not allowed."), 'error' );
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'shop_is_closed_notice' );
function shop_is_closed_notice(){

    if ( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) && !opening_hours() ) {

        $message = esc_html__('The online store is currently closed. You can view products, but purchases are allowed between x-x.', 'woocommerce' );

        wc_add_notice( '<span class="shop-closed">' . $message . '</span>', 'notice' );
    }
}
```

But for some reason, I cannot get this to work. I get no errors and no notices and no matter what I do, all products are non purchasable.

**Perhaps someone can review the code and give some insight?**

Comment: When you are using some existing code please add the link to the original answer, as it's fair this way…

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec

I found parts of the code online and I googled the date formatting and added it using the knowledge that I do have about `if` statements. I was not aware that did code existed somewhere else here as no suggestions came up when I wrote the title of my question.

Sorry if I did something wrong. Your revisited code works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, i understand now, but as the parts of your online picked code, comes from [Time based Enable/Disable Add to Cart in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369492/time-based-enable-disable-add-to-cart-in-woocommerce/54373061#54373061) answer code made by me, I was a bit surprised...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes and complications in your code. Try the following revisited code:

```
// Custom conditional function
function is_shop_open() {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

    $start_time   = mktime('10', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')); // 10h
    $end_time     = mktime('17', '00', '00', date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')); // 17h
    $now_time     = time();
    $allowed_days = in_array( date('N'), array(2, 4, 6) ); // tuesdays, thursdays and saturdays

    return $allowed_days && $now_time >= $start_time && $now_time <= $end_time ? true : false;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'shop_closed_disable_purchases' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'shop_closed_disable_purchases' );
function shop_closed_disable_purchases( $purchasable ) {
    return is_shop_open() ? $purchasable : false;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'shop_open_allow_checkout' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'shop_open_allow_checkout' );
function shop_open_allow_checkout() {
    if ( ! is_shop_open() ) {
        wc_add_notice( __("The online store is currently closed. You can view products, but purchases are not allowed."), 'error' );
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'shop_is_closed_notice' );
function shop_is_closed_notice(){
    if ( ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) && ! is_shop_open() ) {
        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<span class="shop-closed">%s</span>',
            esc_html__('The online store is currently closed. You can view products. But purchases are allowed between x-x.', 'woocommerce' )
        ), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.